# SSIS Setting TransactionOption = Required Not working for ADO.NET connection manager

Tags: ssis

In my SSIS package I have a sequence container first. After that sequence container, I am iterating over a enumerator in a Foreach loop.

Now this foreach loop should be in one transaction and should do all or none.
I am using ADO.NET connection manager. I have used TransactionOption property of ForEach loop as Required.

In sequence container I am able to connect and do all the operations, but when the execution comes into foreach loop the first execute sql task throws the below error and the package fails.

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "ConnName". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

What can be the limitation here? I think it's a very common requirement to use the required option with ADO.NET connection.

Comment: Can it acquire the connection _without_ TransactionOption on? I have never bothered trying to get Transactions working in SSIS. Perhaps there is a SQL-Only way to do this?

Comment: It works with Supported Option. I cannot maintain this in SQL as the foreach loop spans across different servers.

Comment: You're going to have a lot of difficulty getting transactions to work across servers. Foremost you need to set up DTC correctly. If you dig into the error messages further you'll probably find a message to this effect. Again there might be a way to do this without TransactionOption. If you explain further I may be able to help.

Comment: Say I have two servers S1 and S2, both I am connecting with ADO.NET connection manager.
In Foreach loop
First say I am inserting a record in Table T1 of Server S1 DB d1 by running an SP.
Then I am doing some get operation in S1 and S2 to figure out what to insert into S2 Table T2 in DB D2.
Then I am inserting into S2, D2, T2 by running another SP from script task.
Then I am sending an email in a separate task.
Now if any of the above fails, I need to rollback everything and proceed with the next iteration of the foreach loop enumerator variable.
Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: So even if the email fails you want to roll back? You might not know the email failed for 24 hours, and you don't get any confirmation so that could be tricky. Also I'm not certain that a SP inside a script task gets included in a transaction. I think you'll have some difficulties but the first thing to do is to do some research on setting up DTC correctly for cross server transactions.